# Mocha + Chai - no details on errors

Tags: node.js, express, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a problem with mocha and chai. My tests doesn't show errors on failed tests (eg. expected 'a' to be 'b'). [test log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIrN.png)

```
1) Shouldn't publish new post - there is a post with this title
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Sample code:

```
it('Shouldn\'t publish new post - some required fields are empty', done => {
        request(app)
          .post('/posts')
          .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
          .send()
          .end((err, { body }) => {
            if(err) {
              return done(err);
            }

            expect(body).to.have.property('errors');

            return done();
          });
      });
```

I think the problem doesn't directly lay in mocha or chai. My repo: [github repository](https://github.com/sszczep/sCMS-API).

All you need to do is to clone repo, install dependencies and run mongodb. Feel free to create falsy test and see output.

Best Regards

Comment: This assertion may cause an error that isn't handled by test runner, https://github.com/sszczep/sCMS-API/blob/master/test/posts.test.js#L113 . In case it fails, done is never called. It should be wrapped with try..catch. I'm not sure if it's the only problem here but it is one of them.

Comment: So you say i should wrap all expects in try catch block and call done with error?

Comment: In current state, yes. A better way is to switch to promises and handle errors more consistently.

Comment: Does expect return promise so i can chain .catch to it? Haven’t found anything in docs

Comment: I'll post an example shortly. Consider updating the question with relevant code that causes the problem, SO rules require a problem to be comprehensible without following off-site links.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate that. Gonna update asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that errors aren't consistently handled because of nested callbacks. If `expect(body)...` assertion fails, this results in asynchronous error that is never reported to current test with `done(error)`, so all asynchronous Chai assertions should be wrapped with `try..catch`.

A better way is to use promises which Mocha supports natively, [so does Supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example). This allows to consistently handle errors without `done` callback:

```
  it('Shouldn\'t publish new post - outdated/wrong token', async () => {
    const { body } = await request(app)
      .post('/posts')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer blah_blah_blah')
      .send();

    expect(body).to.have.property('errors');
  });
```

Comment: Well, I'd like to thank you very much. Your code doesn't only looks better - it also works as it should in a first place. I didn't know that expect throws an error on fail - now it's very clear to me. Thanks once again.

Comment: Seems like I have to refactor everything now ;) Glad you worked it out. My first time writing tests.